# Map matrix onto other matrix, row by row

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to map a matrix onto another matrix, row by row. Maybe it's better to show this by a simple example:

Let

```
startMatrix <- t(matrix( c(2.3, 1.2, 3.6,   6.9, 5.3, 6.7), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
mapMatrix <- t(matrix( c(1, 1.3, 2, 2.5, 3,   5, 5.6, 6, 6.2, 7), nrow = 5, ncol = 2))
```

Now `mapMatrix` functions as a sort of grid of `startMatrix`, that is `[1, 1.3, 2, 2.5, 3]` is the grid for the first row of `startMatrix` and `[5, 5.6, 6, 6.2, 7]` is the grid for the second row of `startMatrix`. Furthermore, the `startMatrix` is mapped to its nearest element smaller than himself, e.g. `2.3` goes to `2` and `6.7` to `6.2`.

Thus, when mapping `startMatrix` onto `mapMatrix` the outcome should be a matrix that looks as follows:

```
result = [2, 1, 3 ;
          6.2, 5, 6.2]
```

where `;` indicates the end of the row.

I am looking for an approach that is fast, as such procedure will have to be performed for over 10.000 times for matrices with over 100 rows and 1000 columns.

Comment: A place to start: `x = c(2.3, 1.2, 3.6); y = c(1, 1.3, 2, 2.5, 3); y[findInterval(x,y)]`

Comment: is there a reason why you have the mapMatrix as a matrix? I am not understanding the way you currently have the matrix stored. 

1,1.3,2,2.5,3 comes out as position 11,12,21,22,31 of the matrix

Comment: @road_to_quantdom Sorry for the confusion, I corrected the presented code. Now it should make sense.

Comment: @NMeibergen did my answer not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note that each row of mapMatrix must be ascending

```
startMatrix <- t(matrix( c(2.3, 1.2, 3.6,   6.9, 5.3, 6.7), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
mapMatrix <- t(matrix( c(1, 1.3, 2, 2.5, 3,   5, 5.6, 6, 6.2, 7), nrow = 5, ncol = 2))

res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(startMatrix), 
              function(m) mapMatrix[m,][findInterval(startMatrix[m,],mapMatrix[m,])]))
```

Hope this helps!

```
> res
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.0    1  3.0
[2,]  6.2    5  6.2
```

Comment: @N Meibergen please let me know if this is working as you'd like